# Chapter name verticaly in outer margin in toc

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters, rotating

I want to do something like this:

[image]

rotate the chapter name and put it in the outer margin of a book class document. How can I do it?

Comment: This is not a site "Just do it for me"!!

Comment: How many chapters do you plan to have? Do you really want to use a page per chapter in the ToC?